# storing the accessor to innerHtml as a var

Tags: javascript

**I was trying to figure out a way to do the following**

```
var foo = document.body.innerHtml;
```

> then call foo = "testing"
>
> and the body's html would read "testing"

but so far all that happens is innerHtml is returning the value of innerHtml ... *which is expected*

is there any way to store innerHtml and maybe do something like

```
var hold = "innerHtml"

document.body[hold] = "foo"  <--- this does not work by the way
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use `innerHTML` (uppercase) instead of `innerHtml` to get the desired results.

These lines produce the same results:

```
document.body.innerHTML;
document.body["innerHTML"];
document["body"].innerHTML;
document["body"]["innerHTML"];
```

Comment: @samccone, No need, it is a common mistake.

Comment: @samccone Making mistakes is the best way to learn something. The shocking effect will prevent you from making this mistake again, in the future.